# Open <img src> instead of <a href> lightbox effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Is it possible to change this

```
<a href="http://google.com"><img src="/google.png" /></a>
```

Into a working lightbox effect? I suppose the final result would look something like this

```
<a href="/google.png"><img src="/google.png" /></a>
```

And when the lightbox is opened, back to it's original state:

```
<a href="http://google.com"><img src="/google.png" /></a>
```

This is what I have right now..

```
$('a img').each(function() {
$('a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href','/google.png'); 
    });
});
```

And it should change into something like this when the lightbox is opened:

```
$('a img').each(function() {
$('a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href','http://google.com'); 
    });
});
```

If you know about a script that can do this, or if you can help out, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the point of this? Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to add a lightbox effect on images with a link to an external page, and still keep the link.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like Fancybox. This a JQuery lightbox plugin.
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/